# How to directly translate a boolean function to a boolean formula which expressed by conjunctive normal form?

Tags: boolean-algebra

How to interpret the conjunctive normal form to a practical meaning?

Answer (score 0):

`conjunctive normal form` is just confusing termonoligy for "the formula is represented by an AND of ORs", or even more casually, "a bunch of terms anded together, where each term can only include negations and ors". I prefer the terminology `product of sums`.

I agree that the wiki page starts off confusingly, but the numerical examples slightly down from the top are helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form